# Responsive images positioned over responsive image

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I've looked at all the other similar threads and none are relevant to what I'm trying to do. Please look at this image.

[image]

There are 4 parts here. The background and the 3 thermostats on the wall. I want to position each thermostat on the wall with css just as you see them in this image, and inside of `<a>` tags so they are clickable, and have them remain in this same position as the background image gets bigger or smaller depending on viewport size (responsive).

For the life of me I can't figure out how to scale and remain in position these thermostats respective to the background in a responsive manner. Any ideas?

Here is the background image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbPqN.jpg

Comment: is the background going to stay proportional? (cropping and "uncropping" as the viewport is resized) or is it going to scale?

Comment: @thedarklord47 I want it to scale.

Comment: did you look at my answer/is that not what your looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work. As long as you are scaling proportionally, you can use absolute positioning and set everything with percentages so it scales nicely.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OXsviSl.jpg">
    <a class="left" href="#"></a>
    <a class="center"></a>
    <a class="right" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.left, .right, .center {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    top: 42%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 17%;
}
.left {
    left: 18%;
}
.center {
    left: 43%;
}
.right {
    left: 68%;
}
```

Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2L31e0s/6/)

Comment: That doesn't remain positioned proportional to the bg. Here is the bg image: http://i.imgur.com/OXsviSl.jpg

Comment: sorry ignore that. here is an updated version doing what you want. Drag the window to resize. http://jsfiddle.net/L2L31e0s/6/

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact but is pretty close https://jsfiddle.net/nweotw86/

CSS

```
body{
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/sports/1/");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.small{width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;}
.s1{ margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 10%; float: left}
.s2{ margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 10%; float: left}
.s3{ margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 10%; float: left}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="small s1">
  </div>
  <div class="small s2">
  </div>
  <div class="small s3">
  </div>
```

To make them clickable just wrap with an `<a>` like this:

`<a href="#"><div class="small s1"></div></a>`

Comment: That's close, but yeah not it. It all needs to scale proportionally.